# New Table to store row combination of Another Table

Tags: oracle, database-design

I have a table where a customer can define different Levers

CF_LEVER

[image: With Columns ID, LeverID and LeverValue]

I want to give customer an ability to store any combination of these levers for example

FYI - Lever_Name and Lever_Value shown below is for clarity [it will be replaced by Lever_Id[PK of CF_Lever] in table design]
[image: here lever Name and Value is for illustrative purpose, actually it will store LeverId [PK from above table]]

My question is about this Lever_Combo_Id [it signifies what levers combinations are created]. For example in the screenshot above, we created a combination [Lever_Combo_Id] for Product = ABC, SalesChannel = Phone and CampaignId = 4325234. There could be thousands of these combination. Is there a better way to design this table, rather then maintaining a LEVER_COMBO_ID key at application Level.

Comment: `> Is there a better way to design this table?` well IMO yes, *relational* design do not prefere *key - value* storage and `Lever_Combo_Id`seems to be a *redundant* attribute. I'd definitively schedule a *POC* whether your design works for representative data. If you need dynamic attributes make a comparison with the *plain old* `col1, col2,..,coln` approach.

Comment: Thanks Marmite, I agree 'lever_combo_id' does seems redundant, that' why wondering if I am eliminate it.
Use case is a little abstract, there is a bunch of validation we apply during order processing, but business wants to bypass validation/s in some use cases [LEVER COMBINATION] for example, If product is 'XYZ' and sales channel is 'Phone' and state is 'Washington' [this is what I am calling lever combinations] don't apply address validation etc. 
I m not sure about col1, col2... coln approach, as these levers combination can go in thousands